# Structure of $(a,b)$-adic natural numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, semiring

### Introduction

One way to define the [$n$-adic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number#Introduction) is to start from the ring of modular integers $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$ by the ideal $n\mathbb{Z}$. There is an obvious sequence of ring homomorphisms

$$\cdots \to \mathbb{Z}/n^r\mathbb{Z} \cdots \to \mathbb{Z}/n^3\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$

given by expressing the integer modulo $n^r$ in base $n$ notation and taking the last $r-1$ digits (i.e. reducing modulo $n^{r-1}$).

The $n$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_n$ can be defined as the [inverse limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) of this sequence. The standard intuitive picture is that of "integers" with infinitely many digits to the left in base $n$.

Similarly, we can define what I will call the *$(a,b)$-adic natural numbers* starting from a semiring of the form $\mathbb{N}/(a\mathbb{N}+b)$, the quotient of the nonnegative integers $\mathbb{N}$ by the congruence $a\mathbb{N}+b$ (where we identify two numbers whenever they are both greater or equal to $b$ and differ by a multiple of $a$). There is again a sequence of semiring homomorphisms

$$\cdots \to \mathbb{N}/(a^3\,\mathbb{N}+b(a^2+a+1)) \to \mathbb{N}/(a^2\,\mathbb{N}+b(a+1)) \to \mathbb{N}/(a\mathbb{N}+b)$$

given by expressing the numbers in a certain modified base $a$ notation with $b$ extra digits (for $b=1$ it is called [bijective numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration), but I'm not aware of any standard name for it when $b>1$) and truncating. For example, one can express the elements of $\mathbb{N}/(16\mathbb{N}+10)$ with two-digit representatives in base $4$ with $2$ extra digits:

$$0,1,2,3,4,5,12,13,14,15,22,23,24,25,32,33,34,35,42,43,44,45,52,53,54,55$$

and the homomorphism to $\mathbb{N}/(4\mathbb{N}+2)$ is given by taking the units digit.

The semiring of $(a,b)$-adic naturals $\mathbb{N}_{a,b}$ can be then defined analogously as the inverse limit of this sequence. As before, one can think of them as "naturals" with infinitely many digits expressed in this generalized base $a$ notation. Note that the special case $\mathbb{N}_{a,0}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_a$.

---

### Motivation

My motivation to do this is that the exponentiation function $(m,n)\mapsto m^n : \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{N}$ (where we take $0^0=1$) descends to the quotient $\mathbb{N}/(a\mathbb{N}+b)$ whenever $\lambda(a)\mid a$ and $\nu(a)\le b$, where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) and $\nu(a)$ denotes the highest exponent appearing in the prime factorization of $a$. This follows from [this property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Exponential_cycle_length) and the fact that $k^b>b$ for any $b$ and $k>1$.

Since these two conditions imply that $\lambda(a^r)\mid a^r$ and $\nu(a^r)\le b(a^{r-1}+\cdots+a+1)$ for any $r$, exponentiation is well-defined for the entire sequence (in a compatible way, though I won't prove that here), and hence is well-defined when we take the limit. This way we get semirings $\mathbb{N}_{a,b}$ admitting an everywhere defined exponentiation function $(m,n)\mapsto m^n : \mathbb{N}_{a,b}^2 \to \mathbb{N}_{a,b}$, which together with the nonnegative reals $\mathbb{R}^+$ are the only exponentiation-preserving "completions" of $\mathbb{N}$ that I know of.

---

### Question

I would like to know the basic structure of $\mathbb{N}_{a,b}$. It is known that the $n$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_n$ can be decomposed as a direct product of irreducible $\mathbb{Z}_p$ factors, one for each prime $p$ appearing in the prime factorization of $n$.

> Is there an analogous factorization of $\mathbb{N}_{a,b}$ with $b>0$ in terms of some special irreducible $\mathbb{N}_{x,y}$? If not, can these semirings be expressed in terms of other more familiar objects?

I am especially interested in factorizations that preserve the exponential structure whenever it's there, but I would be also satisfied with a general statement for any $a, b$.

Comment: Do you know if there is a CRT like theorem for these rigs in each component of the limit? The reason you get the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_n \cong \prod_{p|n} \mathbb{Z}_p$ is because at each stage of the limit you have the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/n^r\mathbb{Z} \cong \prod_{p|n} \mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z}$ by the CRT; trying to mimic or hope for results on $\mathbb{N}_{a,b}$ that mimic the radical nature of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ would likely follow from something like it or reduce to statements on $(a,b)$ where you *can* do this in a relevant way.

Comment: @Geoff Thanks for your comment! I thought about it, and it looks like a direct analogue of CRT in this setting gives no new factorizations. Since all of the finite rigs are generated from $0$ by repeated addition of $1$, if a product of two such rigs (say $\mathbb{N}/(a\mathbb{N}+b) \times \mathbb{N}/(a'\mathbb{N}+b')$) is to be of this form it should also be additively generated by $(1,1)$. But we can't get one of $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$ this way unless $b=b'=0$ and $\mathrm{gcd}(a,a')=1$. That would imply all of the $\mathbb{N}_{a,b}$ with $b>0$ are irreducible w.r.t. direct product, right?